# insert row in ng-grid of angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am new with angular js.
I am trying to insert row in ng-grid on click of button.
for that I have written a function addNewItems() which updates the json object.
but the grid is not showing the updated object.
here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script/ng-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script/indexStyle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/ng-grid-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
      var myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.gridOptions = { data: myData };

          $scope.addNewItem=function()
          {
           myData.push( { name: 'Test add ', age:29});

           $scope.gridOptions = { data: myData };

          };          
          console.log(myData);
      });

      </script>
</head>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
        <button ng-click="addNewItem()">ADD item</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check it.
Just remove this code from js:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: myData };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.data = myData;
     $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'data' };
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: myData };

    $scope.addNewItem = function() {
        $scope.gridOptions.data.push({ name: 'Test add ', age: 29 });
    };
    console.log($scope.gridOptions.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks @Gurkan Yesilyurt, @anis programmer , @Gaurav ,@kinjal jethva

did this and it started working:

```
var myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
      var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
             $scope.data = myData;
             $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'data' };

            $scope.addNewItem = function() {
                $scope.data.push({ name: 'Test add ', age: 29 });
            };
            console.log($scope.gridOptions.data);
        });
```